# Regex - match all characters from any language and all punctual characters excep

Tags: regex

I wasted several hours on figuring this one out:

```
^[\p{L}\p{P}\d\n\t\r][^<>"'*\\\\\/]*$
```

It's supposed to fail if one char from the list appear [^<>"'*\\/] and is working almost well besides of the situation where one of forbidden symbols is as a first symbol in the string... Can't figure this one out. I've tried several combinations without any success.

Comment: Try: `^(?=[\p{L}\p{P}\d\n\t\r])[^<>"'*\\\\\/]+$`

Comment: You can exclude the listed using a negative lookahead `^(?![^<>"'*\\\/])[\p{L}\p{P}\d\n\t\r][^<>"'*\\\/]*$`

Comment: @anubhava That did the trick, thanks!

Comment: `^[\p{L}\p{P}\d\n\t\r][^<>"'*\\\\\/]*$` = `^(?=[\p{L}\p{P}\d\n\t\r])[^<>"'*\\\\\/]+$`. Why do you say your pattern does not work? It just matches a letter/punctuation/digit/CR/LF/TAB and then any chars other than forbidden chars. Empty strings are not matched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use negated character class for your entire regex match and using a lookahead to assert presence of a chosen character set i.e. `[\p{L}\p{P}\d\n\t\r]` right after start position:

```sh
^(?=[\p{L}\p{P}\d\n\t\r])[^<>"'*\\\\\/]+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fvctIS/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?=[\p{L}\p{P}\d\n\t\r])`: Lookahead to assert presence of given characters at the start
- `[^<>"'*\\\\\/]+`: Match 1+ of any character not listed in given character class
- `$`: End